# C#: Access Violation Exception Error was unhandled

Tags: c#

I'm using an api / dll method. when I run my application I always gets this error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Here is my code

```
charge.CommMethod = PSCharge.CommMethod.TCPIP;
            charge.Port = 31419;
            charge.IPAddress = "192.168.21.139";
            charge.Command = command;
            charge.User = csConfig.pccuser;
            charge.Processor = csConfig.pccprocessor;
            charge.MerchantNumber = csConfig.pccmerchantnum;
            charge.Manual = manual;
            charge.Track = trackdata;
            charge.Amount = amount;
            charge.Card = cardnum;
            charge.ExpDate = expdate;
            charge.member = cardholder;
            charge.Ticket = ticketnumber;
            charge.TroutD = troutd;
            charge.XMLTrans = true;

            PSCharge.FileType filetype = (PSCharge.FileType)3;
            charge.Send(ref filetype);
```

The error is located in this line of code `PSCharge.FileType filetype`

PSCharge.FileType

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PSCharge
{
    [Guid("E42FAC74-F294-4FC3-B0BC-89B48BAD769C")]
    public enum FileType
    {
        TTYPE_CLR = 0,
        TTYPE_INP = 1,
        TTYPE_PRO = 2,
        TTYPE_XML = 3,
        TTYPE_INF = 4,
        TTYPE_BCH = 5,
        TTYPE_DUP = 6,
    }
}
```

Comment: Why cast? `(PSCharge.FileType)3;`

Comment: Is `PSCharge` the library described here?  http://www.pennypacktrust.org/membership/PSCharge.html

Comment: @dtryon I just followed what api sample gives, and that is the way on the manual

Comment: @JonEgerton, cant get rid of this even their sample application has the same error XD

Comment: The crash occurs on the `PSCharge.FileType filetype = (PSCharge.FileType)3;` line? How odd. What is `PSCharge.FileType`? An `enum`?

Comment: @cheol.lui: This stuff seems pretty old - do you know that it still works (on modern operating systems/technologies etc). Do you have a choice whether or not to use it?

Comment: OK, so why don't you just do `PSCharge.FileType filetype = PSCharge.FileType.TTYPE_XML`?

Comment: @nneonneo same error appears

Comment: @JonEgerton, i have no choice. so i cannot fix this?